# arranging elements of vector after using erase()

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std, stdvector

```
for ( i=1; i<=10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);

  // erase the 6th element
  myvector.erase (myvector.begin()+5);

  // erase the first 3 elements:
  myvector.erase (myvector.begin(),myvector.begin()+3);

  cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (i=0; i<myvector.size(); ++i)
```

Is there any way by which I can manipulate erase function so that I don't have to start after i=0 and instead I can store elements from i=1(basically I want to preserve the 1 indexing)./* These code stores elements as 0 indexing although I stored them in 1 indexing. I think the erase function manipulates it  */

Comment: You *are* aware of that all array (as well as vector) indexing in C++ is zero-based? What is the reason to change the semantics of the language itself? What is the *real* problem you want to solve by using one-based indexing?

Comment: The term "indexing" is rather misleading. What is called "index" in C / C++ is typically an *offset* so it starts from 0.

Comment: I want to basically store the elements e.g. 1 to 10 in array and index should be same. but after I use erase function the indexing of element changes to zero indexing. So Is there any way I could use erase()  and preserve the 1 based indexing also.

Comment: Using 1-based indexing in a C++ program is going to confuse the hell out of anyone reading your program, and getting confused yourself when using standard algorithms. Just don't do that. If necessary e.g. to handle user-provided data, adjust indexes just when doing IO, and internally use the regular convention everywhere.

Comment: You didn't store them with `1` indexing. You use a `1` indexed counter to count them but the things you put in the vector were always indexed starting at `0`. You can't really change that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can shift the elements after the desired element down by one index before using a for loop, and then erasing the last element.
For instance you want to erase element 5, you can do element 5 = element 6 and element 6 = element 7... and so on.  When you reach the last element and do element 100(last element) = element 99, you have 2 copies of element 100 at positions 99 and 100.  Then erase the one at position 100.

Comment: Yes, I can always do it in this way but to use erase function is really important in my scenario.

Comment: so what do you want to do after removing the element?

Comment: are you planning to shift the vector and its contents to 1-index it?